# Is there a polynomial time mapping from 'Grover States' to an orthonormal set of vectors

Tags: quantum-state, grovers-algorithm, resource-request

Grover's algorithm solves the problem of 'Quantum Search' which I will describe below:

> Given some oracle, $O_f$, such that $O_f | x \rangle = (-1)^{f(x)} | x \rangle$, find a value of $x$ such that $f(x) = 1$.

The first step of Grover's algorithm is to Hadamard the $| 0 \rangle ^{\otimes N}$ state to arrive at $| + \rangle ^{\otimes N}$.

Then, we apply the oracle $O_f$ on this Hadamard(ed) state. We end up with the state:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^N}} \sum_{i \in \{0, 1\}^N} (-1) ^ {f(x)}|i\rangle \tag 1
$$

Let's consider all the choices of $f(x)$ for arbitrary $N$, let's look at $N = 2$

1. $f(00) = 0, f(01) = 0, f(10) = 0, f(11) = 0$
2. $f(00) = 0, f(01) = 0, f(10) = 0, f(11) = 1$
3. $f(00) = 0, f(01) = 0, f(10) = 1, f(11) = 0$

We could continue, but the pattern is clear; there are $2^{2^N}$ choices of $f(x)$. For each choice of $f(x)$, could we map the state in (1) to a unique $|z \rangle \in \{0, 1\}^{2^N}$ with logarithmic error in polynomial time?

The mapping, $L$, would accept $2$ registers, one has $N$ qubits, and the other (output register) has $2^N$ qubits.

$$
L |x \rangle | 0 \rangle ^{\otimes 2^N} = |x \rangle |y \rangle
$$

It is well known that Grover's algorithm is optimal, so I am fairly certain that this $z$ cannot tell us if $f(x)$ is satisfiable or not. This may not be the case, as it is a $2^N$ qubit register, which is already exponential, but I'm not totally sure.

In any case, is some circuit that does this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an exponential amount of qubits and You want to be able to apply some gate to each one of them. We know an algorithm is efficient if it can be written as polynomially many universal gates. But since You want a gate for each qubit, You must have exponentially many gates to write Your circuit which contradicts it being polynomial